# PHPWord TemplateProcessor uninitialized

Tags: php, web, cpu-word

I have this problem when trying to generate a file from PHPWord template processor where I have this code...

```
    <?php 

require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

$num_written = 0;

class Processor{

    private $templateProcessor;

    private  $objWriter;

function __construct($template){

    $templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor($template);

}


function create_document_from_template($formdata){

        global $num_written;
        $num_written++;

        $name = "Receipt".$num_written.".docx";

         //Notice: Undefined variable: templateProcessor
        $templateProcessor->setValue('name',$formdata["company-name"]);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('address',$formdata["company-address"]);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('city',$formdata["company-city"]);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('can_province',$formdata["company-can-province"]);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('postal_code',$formdata["company-postal-code"]);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('phone_number',$formdata["company-phone-number"]);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('email',$formdata["company-email"]);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('website',$formdata["company-website"]);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('letter_signature_name',$formdata["company-letter-signature-name"]);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('letter_signature_title',$formdata["company-letter-signature-title"]);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('letter_text',$formdata["company-letter-text"]);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('receipt_signature_name',$formdata["company-receipt-signature-name"]);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('charity_number',$formdata["company-charity-number"]);

        $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($templateProcessor, 'Word2007');
        $link_to_save = "../submission/docxs_to_send/".$name;
        $objWriter->save($link_to_save);

        return $name;
       
}

}



?>
```

Where $template is the name of my docx that is in the same directory as my php files

I get the following error: Notice: Undefined variable: templateProcessor

I can't find any documentation on this particular problem, why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing a local variable in the constructor from the `create_document_from_template` method.

In your constructor, you should use `$this->templateProcessor`instead of `$templateProcessor`.

All instances of `$templateProcessor` should be changed to `$this->templateProcessor` in your `create_document_from_template` method.

Your entire code then becomes:

```
<?php 

require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

$num_written = 0;

class Processor{

    private $templateProcessor;

    private  $objWriter;

    function __construct($template){

        $this->templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor($template);

    }


    function create_document_from_template($formdata){

        global $num_written;
        $num_written++;

        $name = "Receipt".$num_written.".docx";

        //Notice: Undefined variable: templateProcessor
        $this->templateProcessor->setValue('name',$formdata["company-name"]);
        $this->templateProcessor->setValue('address',$formdata["company-address"]);
        $this->templateProcessor->setValue('city',$formdata["company-city"]);
        $this->templateProcessor->setValue('can_province',$formdata["company-can-province"]);
        $this->templateProcessor->setValue('postal_code',$formdata["company-postal-code"]);
        $this->templateProcessor->setValue('phone_number',$formdata["company-phone-number"]);
        $this->templateProcessor->setValue('email',$formdata["company-email"]);
        $this->templateProcessor->setValue('website',$formdata["company-website"]);
        $this->templateProcessor->setValue('letter_signature_name',$formdata["company-letter-signature-name"]);
        $this->templateProcessor->setValue('letter_signature_title',$formdata["company-letter-signature-title"]);
        $this->templateProcessor->setValue('letter_text',$formdata["company-letter-text"]);
        $this->templateProcessor->setValue('receipt_signature_name',$formdata["company-receipt-signature-name"]);
        $this->templateProcessor->setValue('charity_number',$formdata["company-charity-number"]);

        $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($this->templateProcessor, 'Word2007');
        $link_to_save = "../submission/docxs_to_send/".$name;
        $objWriter->save($link_to_save);

        return $name;

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, mate. Another proof I'm dumb. It's been so long since I coded in PHP I forgot this particular rule, thank you

Comment: Lol. It happens to all of us